# How to prefix text to Subject?

Tags: vba, outlook

I found code here that almost does what I need.

I used the code to create a macro to add **[SEND SECURE]** to the variable `objMsg`, which should be whatever is in the Subject Line.
Instead it erases text already in the Subject Line.

```vb
Sub InsertSubject()
    
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    
    'Get the currently open message'
    
    Set objMsg = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    
    objMsg.Subject = "[SEND SECURE] " & objMsg.Subject
    
    'Destroy the object to avoid memory leaks'
    objMsg.Send
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I figured out what is going wrong. I need to click out of the Subject line for it to capture. If you never click out of the Subject line before initiating the macro, it will not capture the Subject line.

Comment: I need to update this. I figured out what is going wrong. I need to click out of the Subject line for it to capture. If you never click out of the Subject Line before initiating the Macro, it will not capture the Subject Line. is there anything I can add that would cause it to tab out in a scenario like this? or did I just made it uber complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment about tabbing out of the Subject line, you can simply save the message.

```
Sub InsertSubject()

    Dim objMsg As MailItem

    'Get the currently open message'
    Set objMsg = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    objMsg.Save

    objMsg.Subject = "[SEND SECURE] " & objMsg.Subject

    objMsg.Send

    'Destroy the object to avoid memory leaks'
    Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I had been looking into the .Save option after I said that, but I was putting it in the wrong place.

Everything works perfectly now. Thank you so much!